# How do linear operators acting on paths of Gaussian processes influence the covariance function?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes

It is well-known that applying a linear transformation $A$ on an $n$-dimensional centered Gaussian distribution with covariance matrix $\Sigma$ results in another centered Gaussian distribution with covariance matrix $A\Sigma A^T$.

I am interested in generalisations of this property for Gaussian processes. So, let's say we have a centered Gaussian process $X$ over an intervall $[0,t]$ with paths a.s. in a certain function space $V$ and a linear operator $T:V\to W$, where $W$ is another function space (if necessary, over the same intervall).  Intuitively, I would guess that $T(X)$ is again a centered Gaussian process, which could be proved by looking at the finite-dimensional distributions of the process, if I'm not mistaken.

The question is now, what can be said about the covariance function of $T(X)$ given the covariance function of $X$, e.g. something similar to the "$A\Sigma A^T$"-expression above? Is there any general statement (even with some additional assumptions like continuity or compactness of $T$) and if so, where can I find it?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is long overdue, but I think this manuscript and the references therein can be of your interest: https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.03134.